# PLSQL - IN clause using variable with multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am looping a statement and extracting the IDs and putting it into a variable:

```
declare
  l_id  NUMBER;

BEGIN

     FOR i IN 1..l_row_count
        loop
            l_id := to_number(apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'rows[%d].id', 
                                                        p0 => i, p_values => l_values
                                                        )
                                );
     end loop:
```

I am trying to get all the ids and then run a select statement where this list of IDs will be used inside of a where statement. So the full code would look like this:

```
    declare
      l_id  NUMBER;
      l_id_list [SOME_TYPE_NOT_SURE];
    
    BEGIN
    
         FOR i IN 1..l_row_count
            loop
                l_id := to_number(apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'rows[%d].id', 
                                                            p0 => i, p_values => l_values
                                                            )
                                    );
                //somehow add l_id to the l_id_list
 
         end loop:

        SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE someid IN (l_id_list);

END;
```

I haven't been able to get it to work. I am not an expert in PLSQL, but I tried using arrays or trying to concat the l_id_list as a string, but I am unable to get it work. Basically all I am trying to do is create a list of all the IDs, then run a select statement to see if these IDs exist in this other table.

Comment: You need to learn about Oracle collections(VARRAYS and Nested tables in your case for SQL->PL/SQL): https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the type globally:

```sql
CREATE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Then you can initialise the list and then, in each iteration of the loop, `EXTEND` the list and assign the value and, finally, use the `MEMBER OF` operator or `IN` with a subquery and table collection expression:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_id_list NUMBER_LIST := NUMBER_LIST();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..l_row_count
  LOOP
    l_id_list.EXTEND;
    l_id_list(l_id_list.COUNT) := to_number(
                                    apex_json.get_varchar2(
                                      p_path   => 'rows[%d].id', 
                                      p0       => i,
                                      p_values => l_values
                                    )
                                  );
  END LOOP;

  SELECT *
  -- BULK COLLECT INTO ...
  FROM   mytable
  WHERE  someid MEMBER OF l_id_list;

  -- or

  SELECT *
  -- BULK COLLECT INTO ...
  FROM   mytable
  WHERE  someid IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(l_id_list));
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case `l_id_list`'s type must be declared globally and as collection-type. Locally defined types cannot be used as collections, so cannot be used inside `in`-clause.

```
 declare
      l_id  NUMBER;
      l_id_list [SOME_GLOBAL_COLLECTION_TYPE];
    
    BEGIN
    
         FOR i IN 1..l_row_count
            loop
                l_id := to_number(apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'rows[%d].id', 
                                                            p0 => i, p_values => l_values
                                                            )
                                    );
                //somehow add l_id to the l_id_list
 
         end loop:

        SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE someid IN (select * from table(l_id_list));
END;
```